# wso2 data mapper failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When i tried to use the data mapper mediator I always get an error. I tried mapping the json response to xml.

```
[2016-07-14 14:05:26,684] ERROR - omdbapi DataMapper mediator : mapping failed
XML not well-formed. Error occurred while processing start element event
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.readers.XMLReader.read(XMLReader.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.input.InputModelBuilder.buildInputModel(InputModelBuilder.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.engine.core.mapper.MappingHandler.doMap(MappingHandler.java:59)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.transform(DataMapperMediator.java:244)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediator.datamapper.DataMapperMediator.mediate(DataMapperMediator.java:209)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:49)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:160)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:320)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:336)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:541)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:252)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my api. I just use the omdbapi to give an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/omdbapi" name="omdbapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/*">
        <inSequence>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address trace="disable" uri="http://www.omdbapi.com/"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="XML" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="XML"/>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to map JSON-> XML, you need to specify in the Data Mapper Mediator configuration.
Make sure you set the input type as JSON.

And there have been beta2 release on wso2 esb. So try using beta2 packs for esb [runtime](https://github.com/wso2/product-esb/releases/tag/v5.0.0-BETA2) and [tooling](https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-esb/releases/tag/v5.0.0-BETA2). Use the latest pack and try.

Comment: well i fixed that problem but i still cant get the mapped output.
here's my out
`<outSequence>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig_inputSchema.json" inputType="JSON" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/omdbapiConfig_outputSchema.json" outputType="XML"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>`

Comment: Can you specify the input message you sent and inputschema file.

Comment: Here is the input message that i use which is the response from the api http://pastebin.com/AJ0wiz1r and here is the inputschema file http://pastebin.com/7npvfWvU

Comment: I have test it with latest pack of WSO2 ESB and WSO2 ESB Tooling which will released today (5.0.0 Beta2). :) And it is working fine with the above mentioned input file.

Comment: And the input message you used may be not supported by runtime since the key value is not inside "" values. Can you check it also?